# Launching from .bat not working the same as running .ps1 directly

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to make a script that people can doubleclick to run a set of commands that changes occasionally. In linux I run a .sh that wgets another sh (that I can change when needed) and runs it. I'm looking for a similar solution for Windows.

I looked into PowerShell but found out it needs to be run from a .bat to allow double clicking, so now I have the following:

`foo.bat` file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%bar.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

that calls `bar.ps1`:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxx/bar2.ps1 -OutFile bar2.ps1
```

Running `bar.ps1` from PowerShell works fine and downloads `bar2.ps1`, but running the batch file does not, or at least not to the directory both files are in (can't find it anywhere, though I guess it might be a working directory problem still?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch file is running the PowerShell script with elevated privileges. Doing this changes the working directory to `C:\Windows\system32` (for security reasons), so you'll most likely find the downloaded file there. To get the ouptut file in the same directory as the script you could change the PowerShell script like this:

```
$dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$filename = 'bar2.ps1'
$url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxx/$filename"

Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile "$dir/$filename"
```

With that said, why are you running a download script with elevated permissions in the first place? Don't do that.